# Multiple Project in Same Solution with inter-project depedencies - Deploy using Azure DevOps - CICD Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a Github repo that contains Visual Studio solution having multiple projects and want to setup Azure DevOps pipelines separately for the projects which will trigger according to the commit.

Solution
1) DataFactory 
2) BusinessLogic
3) DataAcessLayer
4) WebAPI
5) UI

Also, One project have inter-project dependencies for other projects like 
1 WebAPI => DataFactory & BusinessLogic
2 BusinessLogic => DataFactory & DataAcessLayer

So, This can be managed?
- I already tried [paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55048163/azure-devops-1-solution-multiple-projects-ci-cd)

I'm not able to see any path filter here:

[image]

Please let me know how it can be done.

Comment: It seems that Sajeetharan's answer helps to resolve your issue, you can consider [accepting it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that more members can benefit from the useful info. Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you don't get to see in the UI, you should be able to configure it using the YAML file for Github Repositories, Here is a [guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#paths).

```
# specific path build
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - releases/*
  paths:
    include:
    - docs/*
    exclude:
    - docs/README.md
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Your Highness! :) This worked for resolving path trigger related issues.

Answer (score 1):

You are using "Other Git" as source (repository) and that does not provide path filters. Try using Azure Repos Git / GitHub / GitHub Enterprise as source, those do provide path filters.

Comment: Yes, I got this. Other Git source doesn't contain path filter options