# Can we use single CI CD pipeline for two different .net application solution?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have checked this link [Azure DevOps: 1 Solution Multiple Projects CI/CD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55048163/azure-devops-1-solution-multiple-projects-ci-cd) which is related to one solution with multiple project.

Can we use multiple solution in single CI CD pipeline ? where we have different artifacts for each solution and app servers to deploy.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the code is in the same repository there are no issues to using multiple .net solutions or any other type.

You can also publish multiple artifacts from the same pipeline

Answer (score 0):

If you are using YAML pipeline, you can check out multiple repositories in your pipeline.

Pipelines often rely on multiple repositories. You can have different repositories with source, tools, scripts, or other items that you need to build your code. By using multiple `checkout` steps in your pipeline, you can fetch and check out other repositories in addition to the one you use to store your YAML pipeline.

**Repository declared using a repository resource :**

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: MyGitHubRepo # The name used to reference this repository in the checkout step
    type: github
    endpoint: MyGitHubServiceConnection
    name: MyGitHubOrgOrUser/MyGitHubRepo
  - repository: MyAzureReposGitRepository
    type: git
    name: MyProject/MyAzureReposGitRepo

steps:
- checkout: MyGitHubRepo
- checkout: MyAzureReposGitRepository
```

**Repository declared using inline syntax :**

If your repository doesn't require a service connection, you can declare it inline with your checkout step.

```
steps:
- checkout: git://MyProject/MyRepo # Azure Repos Git repository in the same organization
```

For details ,please refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#repository-declared-using-a-repository-resource).