# build and deploy two project in one azure web app using azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I have two projects (Web & Web API) in dotnet core under one solution. I am able to deploy single though Azure devops and Azure web app. But i want to build both project in azure devops single pipeline and publish to single azure web app with different path mapping. i tried all the possible way to build and deploy both project under one pipeline to one azure web app. it's not working. need guidance.

Comment: Any update to the issue?

Answer (score 0):

- Create multiple Projects in a single solution and save in a single repository.
- Navigate to **Pipelines**, click **New** and then **New build pipeline**.
- Click **Use the classic editor**.

[image]

By default, the first repository (Azure Repos Git) will be selected for you, just click **Continue**.

Select **ASP.NET Core** and then click **Apply**.
From here, we will make use of the **[Path Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops)** properties in the **Triggers** settings for the `build`.

- With the proper path to the project in the **Path filter** only the proper `Builds` spin up, and any projects untouched do not trigger a build.
- Each build has it's own `release` which then deploys the specified app to it's own destination.
- Under **Path filters**, we need to specify the paths to look for file changes.
- Check **Enable continuous integration**.
- Under **Branch Filters**, click **Add** and add the `master` branch.
- Under **Path filters**, we need to specify the paths to look for file changes, you want to include `/SampleWebApp` and `/SampleWebApi`.
- Click **Save & queue** and then **Save & queue**.
- Repeat for the **SampleWebApi** project.

Please refer [Multiple Project Deployment with Azure DevOps](http://www.mattruma.com/multiple-project-deployment-with-azure-devops/) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55048163/azure-devops-1-solution-multiple-projects-ci-cd?noredirect=1&lq=1) for more details.

Comment: Thank you @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT will try your provided solution.