# Azure DevOps: CI build for one project in the Solution [.Net Core]

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I have a solution in .Net core containing multiple projects.

- src/Api/[ProjName].Api
- [ProjName].FrontEnd

We are using the Azure pipelines using Azure DevOPS and we need to have a complete separate build pipelines for each of the mentioned projects. I have tried to use "Path Filters" but couldn't accomplish this. My pipeline creates a drop from the whole solution.
Already reviewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55048163/azure-devops-1-solution-multiple-projects-ci-cd) but not found the solution.

Can anyone help on this?

The Source Code Path

[image]

Azure DevOPS CI Pipeline

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On the .Net build task, you can set the value of the field "**`Path to project(s)`**" to be the path of a specified project in the solution. The wildcard expression "**`**/*.csproj`**" will match and build all the C# projects in the solution.

[image]

For your case, after .Net build task, the you need to use the [**Copy Files task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to copy the artifact files from the build output path to **`$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`**.

[image]

Then use the **Publish Artifacts task ** to publish the artifact files from **`$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

we use this code to achieve that for our multi-project solution:

```
trigger:
 branches:
  include:
  - master
 paths:
  include:
    - src/Project1

pool:
  name: 'Default'
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
  - script: dotnet build src\Project1\Project1.csproj --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
    displayName: 'Building. Configuration: "$(buildConfiguration)"'
    name: 'build_solution'
    continueOnError: 'false'

  - script: dotnet test src\Project1\Project1.csproj --no-build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
    displayName: 'Running tests'
    name: 'run_tests'
    continueOnError: 'false'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Publishing'
    name: 'publish'
    continueOnError: false
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      publishWebProjects: false
      projects: '**/Project1.csproj'
      arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --no-build --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      zipAfterPublish: true

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: 'Publish build artifact'
    name: 'publish_build_artifact'
    continueOnError: false
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      ArtifactName: 'Project1'
      publishLocation: 'Container'
```